# replace special characters in oracle sqldeveloper

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to replace all occurrences of | and enter to ' in oracle sqldeveloper but its giving error.

SELECT replace("test|123|333",'|','\'') FROM DUAL;

can someone help me with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're statement is invalid, here is the correct one:

```
SELECT replace('test|123|333','|','''') FROM DUAL;
```

In SQL, text value starts and ends with single quote.

Comment: I want to replace with ' not \